# Code to programmatically create and activate a seller for Dokan plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, dokan

Is there sample code to programmatically create and activate a seller account for Dokan plugin?

I tried the below:

```
$email = 'abc@gmail.com';
$pwd = 'admin123';
$first_name = 'fname';
$last_name = 'lname';
$store_name = 'TestStore';
$custom_store_url = '';
$phone = '';


$newUserId = wc_create_new_customer( $email, $first_name, $pwd );
$newUser = get_user_by( 'email', $email );
update_user_meta( $newUserId, "first_name", $first_name );
update_user_meta( $newUserId, "last_name", $last_name );
update_user_meta( $newUserId, "dokan_enable_selling", 'yes' );
update_user_meta( $newUserId, "dokan_store_name", $store_name );

$user = wp_signon( array( 'user_login' => $newUser->user_login, 'user_password' => $pwd ), false );
if ( is_a( $user, 'WP_User' ) ) {
    $user_id = $user->ID;
    if( $user ) {
        wp_set_current_user( $user_id, $user->user_login );
        wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id );
        update_user_meta( $newUserId, "wp_capabilities", str_replace('customer','seller',$user->capabilities);
        do_action( 'wp_login', $user->user_login );
    }
}
echo $customerId = ( is_user_logged_in() ) ? get_current_user_id() : 0;exit(0);
```

Can anyone validate is this the right way or identify, what I am missing?

Answer (score -1):

```
$email            = 'abc@gmail.com';
$pwd              = 'admin123';
$first_name       = 'fname';
$last_name        = 'lname';
$store_name       = 'TestStore';
$custom_store_url = '';
$phone            = '';

$newUserId      = wc_create_new_customer( $email, $first_name, $pwd );
$newUserId      = wp_update_user( array( 'ID'         => $newUserId,
    'role'       => 'seller',
    'first_name' => $first_name,
    'last_name'  => $last_name,
) );
$newUser        = get_user_by( 'email', $email );
$dokan_settings = array(
    'store_name'     => $store_name,
    'social'         => array(),
    'payment'        => array(),
    'phone'          => $phone,
    'show_email'     => 'no',
    'location'       => '',
    'find_address'   => '',
    'dokan_category' => '',
    'banner'         => 0,
);
update_user_meta( $newUserId, 'dokan_enable_selling', 'yes' );
update_user_meta( $newUserId, 'dokan_profile_settings', $dokan_settings );
update_user_meta( $newUserId, 'dokan_store_name', $dokan_settings['store_name'] );

$user = wp_signon( array( 'user_login' => $newUser->user_login, 'user_password' => $pwd ), false );
```